# Label text not updating in MUIDataTable ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I want to add multi language option in mui Datatables. I can change the translations but when I want to change language, I tried to give another object with the other translations (this object if I do console log I can see the changes) but the label texts not change.

I used a contextProvider to change the language selected and then get the specific dictionary with the translations.

Is a class component, so I did a static contextType with the correct provider.

Is there any possibility to re-render the element with another options or something like that?

```
options = {
 textLabels: this.context.translation.dataTables.textLabels
};

return(
 <MUIDataTable
   title={this.context.language.value}
   data={data}
   columns={columns}
   options={options}
 />
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach to re-render **Mui-Datatables** its updating the key of the table

**key={this.context.language.value}**

```js
<MUIDataTable
   key={this.context.language.value}
   title={this.context.language.value}
   data={data}
   columns={columns}
   options={options}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force React component rendering:

- There are multiple ways to force a React component rendering but they are essentially the same.  The first is using `this.forceUpdate()`, which skips `shouldComponentUpdate`:

```js
someMethod() {
    // Force rendering without state change...
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

- Assuming your component has a state, you could also call the following:

```js
someMethod() {
    // Force rendering with a simulated state change
    this.setState({ state: this.state });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. But the states is working, I tried to change the data and the title, this last as you can see, changes with the context and it works. But I can't change the options and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

use **customRowRender** Function in the options and manipulate table with respect to language

Override default row rendering with custom function.

**customRowRender(data, dataIndex, rowIndex) => React Component**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just want to change the textLabels option. I can change data prop and title prop. But I can't change options props

Answer (score 0):

In MUIDataTable, We can override label name by providing label in MUIDataTableColumnDef options while making column.

Example :

```
const columns: MUIDataTableColumnDef[] = [
    {
        name: 'Id',
        label: 'ID',
        options: {
            download: false,
            customBodyRenderLite: (index: number) => {
                const desc: Description = evenMoreAbout[index]
                return <BasicInfo obj={desc} setIconClicked={setIconClicked} />
            }
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'id',
        label: 'ID',
        options: {
            display: 'excluded',
            download: true,
            customBodyRender: desc => desc.id
        }
    }]
```

Even though if we still want to over ride the label name on some condition of data using customHeadLabelRender ... we can as like below example

```
const columns: MUIDataTableColumnDef[] = [
    {
        name: 'Id',
        label: '',
        options: {
            download: false,
            customBodyRenderLite: (index: number) => {
                const desc: Description = evenMoreAbout[index]
                return <BasicInfo obj={desc} setIconClicked={setIconClicked} />
            },
            customHeadLabelRender: (dataIndex: number, rowIndex: number) => {
                return 'ID';
            }
        }
    }
]
```